# Finding good bases to represent any rectangular matrix as a block matrix with identity submatrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, diagonalization

This question is a generalization of [Finding bases such that the matrix representation is a block matrix where one submatrix is the identity matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1354357/finding-bases-such-that-the-matrix-representation-is-a-block-matrix-where-one-su) .

#### Question

For any linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ where $n\neq m$, 
given its matrix representation $[L]^{\mathcal{E}_n}_{\mathcal{E}_m}$, say $\begin{pmatrix}a_{1,1} & \dots & a_{1,n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{m,1} & \dots & a_{m,n}\end{pmatrix}$, with respect to the standard basis $\mathcal{E}_n$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{E}_m$ of $\mathbb{R}^m$, 
must we be able to find basis $\alpha$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\beta$ for $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that
$[L]^{\alpha}_{\beta} = \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{I}_{r}  & \mathbf{O} \\ \mathbf{O}& \mathbf{O} \end{pmatrix}$,
where $\mathbf{I}_{r}$ is an $r\times r$ identity matrix with $r=\text{Rank}(L)$, and $\mathbf{O}$'s are some zero matrices?
If yes, what are the systematic ways (if any) to find it?

#### Thoughts

My professor casually said that it is true and left it as an exercise, giving hints along the lines of "do row / column operations to get the change of basis matrices".
It was used in subsequent proofs in the class so probably it is really  true.

The closest I know / can find (which are more sophisticated than "just" row / column operations) are

1. Diagonalization, which is for $n=m$ and the diagonal entries are eigenvalues, and
2. Singular Value Decomposition, which is for $n\neq m$ but still gives $\begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{D}  & \mathbf{O} \\ \mathbf{O}& \mathbf{O} \end{pmatrix}$ only where $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix.

$ \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{I}_{r}  & \mathbf{O} \\ \mathbf{O}& \mathbf{O} \end{pmatrix}$ sounds too good to be true... (but I am still a beginner in Linear Algebra)
I wonder if some more conditions are needed?

I also tried a bunch of keywords in Google but could not find anything.
(are there names for "a block matrix with identity submatrix"?)
I apologize if my question is not phrased in the standard way.
I would appreciate if there are some pointers.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Gaussian elimination.

Each Gaussian 'row move' can be represented by an elementary row matrix; similarly for column moves. Hence applying the Gaussian row/column operations is effectively the same as $$E_rAE_c = \begin{pmatrix}I&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}=:I'$$ where $E_r=E_1\cdots E_k$ is the product of the row operations applied to $A$. So taking their inverses gives $A=E_r^{-1}I'E_c^{-1}$ as required.

2. Singular value decomposition.

If SVD is known for $A$, that is, $A=UDV^\top$ (with $U,V$ square), then write $$D=\begin{pmatrix}P&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}R&O\\O&I\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I&O\\O&O\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}R&O\\O&I\end{pmatrix}=R'I'R'$$ where $P$ is a diagonal matrix of strictly positive numbers $\sigma>0$ and $R$ is also diagonal consisting of their square roots $\sqrt{\sigma}$. Then $$A=(UR')I'(R'V)^\top.$$

Between the two, however, the first requires many less steps than SVD. To use SVD to find the called-for bases is like using a golden hammer on a rusty nail.